# Prove that if $m$ is a finite measure, then $m\left( \bigcap^{k}_{i=1}A_{i} \right)\leq \sqrt[k]{\prod^{k}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove that if $m$ is a finite measure, then

> $$ m\left( \bigcap^{k}_{i=1}A_{i} \right)\leq \sqrt[k]{\prod^{k}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )}$$

**MY TRAIL**

For $n=1,m\left( A_{1} \right)\leq m(A_{1} )$

We assume it is true for some $k\geq 0,$ i.e.
$$ m\left( \bigcap^{k}_{i=1}A_{i} \right)\leq \sqrt[k]{\prod^{k}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )}$$
So, 
\begin{align} m\left( \bigcap^{k+1}_{i=1}A_{i} \right)&\leq \sqrt[k+1]{\prod^{k+1}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )}\\&= \sqrt[k+1]{\prod^{k}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )\times m(A_{k+1} )}\end{align}

I got stuck at this point. I know that I have not used the hypothesis that $m$ is finite. Can anyone show me how to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The measure of  $\bigcap^{k}_{i=1}A_{i} $ is at most the measure of the $A_i$ with the smallest measure since it is a subset of this $A_i$. Then use that the geometric mean of $k$ nonnegative numbers is at least the minimum of these numbers.

Comment: If I understood you, do you mean $$ m\left( \bigcap^{k}_{i=1}A_{i} \right)\leq \min m(A_{i} )\leq \sqrt[k]{\prod^{k}_{i=1}m(A_{i} )}?$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get the second part of the hint! I mean the geometric mean part. Could you please, expatiate?

Comment: Yes for the first question. For the second, show that $(a_1....a_k)^{1/k} \geq \min_i a_i$ for nonnegative $a_i$.